# python opencv match HOG descriptor using BFMatcher knn

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am using python opencv BFMatcher to match HOG descriptors of different patches of the same image to find out for copy paste forgery. where patches were obtained from SLIC algorithm in scikit library.
The code is as follows,

```
def matchWithHOGKNN(SegmentValueList: list, segments: numpy.ndarray, imageColor: numpy.ndarray):
'''prepare the HOG descriptor'''

hog = HOGDescriptor((32, 32), (16, 16), (8, 8), (8, 8),9) 

'''iteratively looping over the list of segment values'''
    for segVal in noSIFTkeySegValList:
        rows, cols = numpy.where(segments == segVal)
    '''iterating the HOG sliding window'''
         for y in range(min(rows), max(rows) - detection_window_row, 4):
           for x in range(min(cols), max(cols) - detection_window_col, 4):
             roi = greyImage[y:y + detection_window_row, x:x + detection_window_col]

'''add the descriptor with segment value'''
      dictionary[SegVal(segVal)] = hog.compute(img=roi)

        # '''after iterating the HOG kernel over the segment, add the descriptors to the dictionary'''
        # dictionary[segVal] = temp_h_o_g_descriptors


'''after iterating over all the 
compare between the descriptors of each segment obtained
here in the dictionary key->segment_value | value->HOG descriptor'''

'''prepare a numpy array of HOG descriptors'''
hog_descriptors = numpy.array(list(dictionary.values()))
list_of_keys = numpy.array(list(dictionary.keys()))


'''prepare the BF matcher'''
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(hog_descriptors, hog_descriptors, k=2)

'''iterating over matches to get the best matches'''
for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
    distance = abs(n.distance- m.distance)

    # if distance < minimum_distance:  # for testing purposes
    #     minimum_distance = distance  # for testing purposes

    if distance < 0.4:
        '''this is taken as a match'''
        '''obtain the segment values for matched descriptors'''
        keyValue1 = list_of_keys[m.queryIdx].segmentValue
        keyValue2 = list_of_keys[n.trainIdx].segmentValue
```

The problem here is that the patches matched are not the desired patches. Help to detect the issue is appreciated.

some example image is as below,
original image taken form the data set at [Copy-Move Forgery Detection and Localization](http://lci.micc.unifi.it/labd/2015/01/copy-move-forgery-detection-and-localization/)
[image]

cloned image
[image: cloned the right hand side window]

clone detected image
[image: marked patches are in white color]

Thank you.

Comment: Could you attach some images to show where you're getting undesired matches?

Comment: @VaibhavMehrotra I have updated the question to include the images. the right hand side house's window area is the cloned part, which is expected to be detected.